# Am I using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, queueuserworkitem

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC app. 
I wanted to spawn few threads when a event occurs, I dont care for the return value 
of my threads and I wanted to make a async call so I am using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem ,

```
 public event SomeEventHandler SomeEvent;

private void SomeEventhappened(UserProfile arg)
        {
          SomeEventHandler handler = SomeEvent;
          if (handler != null)
          {
            // handler(currentUser);
            foreach (SomeEventHandler wc in handler.GetInvocationList())
            {
              SomeEventHandler wc2 = wc;
              ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                    delegate { wc2(arg); }
               );
            }
          }
        }
```

I have attached the event handler function to the event

This is how I raise the event,

```
this.SomeEventhappened(userProfile);   //Here the event is raised
```

All the above code is happening in the same class. Only the event handler functions are in other class
Do I need to kill my threads after they complete? 
Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What about just calling "Invoke" ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to use the `ThreadPool` in an ASP.NET application is [not to use it](http://csharpfeeds.com/post/5415/Dont_use_the_ThreadPool_in_ASP.NET.aspx).  ASP.NET itself uses the same `ThreadPool`, so whenever you queue a work item, you are taking away resources that ASP.NET needs to actually serve pages.

For the sake of completeness, I'll add that the "preferred" alternative would be to simply create a standard `Thread` for the work.  You will have to code the work method more defensively, as a bare thread does not have the same level of protection as a `ThreadPool` thread, but as long as you do this then you'll be safe and won't cannibalize ASP.NET requests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire your event asynchronously you can simply call BeginInvoke on each delegate.  There is no need to queue it as a work item.

Comment: IF I use BeginInvoke I have to call EndInvoke also which I dont want to do

Answer (score 0):

I think there is AsyncController in ASP.NET MVC 2 which you should take advantage of instead of using directly the ThreadPool,